# MSIX Packaging Tool and MFC Support (for Windows Store)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, windows-store-apps, msix

**Hi!**

Could someone answer my question, please?
Does the MSIX Packaging Tool support VC++/MFC?

My manifest has declaration:

```
<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.29016.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
```

Is this element OK for MFC deployment?

I highly appreciate the support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VC redist dependency declared in your MSIX package looks ok, assuming you declared it in the right place in your manifest. What is your problem? Does your application fails to run?

Also, is this an application still under development? If so, I recommend you using Visual Studio and the **Windows Application Packaging Project** to build your MSIX, not the MSIX Packaging Tool (which is intended to be used only by IT pros when repackaging applications).

- [How create an MSIX with Visual Studio](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-package-in-visual-studio.html)

Extract MSFT docs:

> In the package manifest for your app, add the following  element under the  node. Make sure you replace the Name and MinVersion values with the values you copied in the previous step. The following example specifies a dependency for the current version of the VC 14.0 framework package.

Comment: Thank you very much, a good idea for the future.